# Handle infinite lists in CoffeeScript

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, coffeescript

In Haskell I can do this to handle an infinite list.

```
takeWhile (<1000) [1 ..]
```

Is there a way to this in CoffeeScript?

Comment: Note that the `,2` is redundant in that code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[StreamJS](http://streamjs.org/) enables the creation of 'infinite' lists in javascript.

Using it's (rough) [coffeescript port](https://github.com/MichaelBlume/coffeestream):

```
# Stream.range() creates a list from 1...Infinity
numbers = Stream.range().until (x) -> x > 1000
```

Comment: Link to the SICP [section on streams](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-24.html#%_sec_3.5) mentioned on the streamJS site.

Answer (score 3):

Not as built in primitives, but they can be hacked in as in most other languages. At least someone is toying around with it in CoffeeScript; see https://github.com/swannodette/fun.coffee/blob/master/src/fun.coffee . For solutions that seem less "hacked in", you might want to read up on CPS and support for proper tail calls, see http://blog.mozilla.com/dherman/2011/01/30/proper-tail-calls-in-harmony/ .